# Make each post on its own unique div

Tags: php, css

A couple of months ago, I asked a similar question like this and the answer that where given worked for me. I now have another change I would like to add to my page. I would like that each post I create has its own unique div. My page currently looks like this: [image]

the previous question helped me break the div each 3 post, so what I tried was within the if statement that creates a new dive each 3 div was to add another if which would break each 1 div so that each post has its own div and it still breaks to a new div section each 3, maybe I just complicated everything with my description, but I want to get something like: [image]

Here is my code

CSS:

```
.column {
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 5px black;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffa500;
}
```

PHP:

```
else {
 $break = 0;
        $nRows = $connection->prepare("SELECT post_id, post_title, 
                                             post_author, post_file, post_time
                                             FROM posts
                                             ORDER BY post_id DESC");
        $nRows->execute();

        if($nRows->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($row = $nRows->fetch()) {
                $post_title = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['post_title']);
                $post_author = $ed->encrypt_decrypt('decrypt',$row['post_author']);
                $post_file = $row['post_file'];
                $post_date = $row['post_time'];
                // Create a new div each 3 columns
                if ($break % 3 === 0) {
                    echo '<br><div class="column"><br>';
                }
                $break++;
                ?>
                <!-- Blog Content BEGIN Display-->
                <div class="box"><?php
                    // Display the content
                    $file_parts = pathinfo($post_file);
                    if(isset($file_parts['extension'])) {
                        switch ($file_parts['extension']) {
                            case "jpg":
                                if(!empty($post_file)) { ?>
                                    <img src="post/postFiles/<?php echo $post_file;?>"><?php
                                }
                                break;
                            case "mp4":?>
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <video preload="auto" loop muted>
                                        <source src="post/postFiles/<?php echo $post_file;?>">
                                    </video>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Preview video on hover -->
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function () {
                                        $(".thumbnail").hover(function () {
                                            $(this).children("video")[0].play();
                                        }, function () {
                                            var el = $(this).children("video")[0];
                                            el.pause();
                                            el.currentTime = 0;
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script><?php
                                break;
                            case "": // Handle file extension for files ending in '.'
                            case NULL: // Handle no file extension
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Title URL Variable
                    $urlFetchPostId = '<h2><a href="post/postFetch/fetchByTitle/fetchByPT.php?post_id=';
                    $urlFetchPostTitle = '&post_title=';
                    $urlFetchPostAuthor = '&post_author=';

                    echo $urlFetchPostId . $row['post_id'] . $urlFetchPostAuthor. $row['post_author']. $urlFetchPostTitle . $row['post_title'] . '"' . 'class="link-post-title" style="font-family: Arial">' . " ". $post_title . '</a></h2>';

                    // Author/User URL Variable
                    $urlFetchPostUser = '<a href="post/postFetch/fetchByAuthor/fetchByPA.php?post_author=';
                    echo $urlFetchPostUser . $row['post_author'] . '"' . 'class="link-post-author" style="font-family: Arial">' . " ". strtoupper($post_author) . '</a>';

                    // Posted Date
                    echo '<br><p style="font-family: Arial">Posted on ' . $post_date . '</p>';
                    ?>
                </div><?php
                if ($break % 3 === 0) {
                    echo '<br></div><br>';
                }?>
                <!-- Blog Content END Display --><?php
            }
        } else { ?>
            <p style="color: darkgoldenrod" class="mssgAlign"><u>NO RECORDS</u></p><?php
        }
        $nRows = null;
    }
```

Any help, tip or improvement suggestion is welcomed

Comment: Just curious - why you prefer to reinvent the wheel instead of using Bootstrap, which was created for such things?

Comment: This is what flexbox is for. Check out [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#specifying_what_elements_to_lay_out_as_flexible_boxes).

Answer (score -1):

You want to use margins. Margins specify a buffer around the outside of your container. As opposed to padding, which specifies buffer inside the container. Add this to your css

```
.column {
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 5px black;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffa500;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```